# Python3 elevenlabs ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing'

Tags: python, python-import, type-hinting, python-typing, literals

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKxzy.png)

See image. What am i doing wrong? I'm a newbie with python, i don't have a clue what i am doing wrong
ps: i previously installed the package elevenlabs with 'pip3 install elevenlabs')

Searched for answers to fix it, previously also added some code and a package for the command 'typing', but it did not do the trick

Comment: `typing.Literal` was introduced in Python 3.8. You're using 3.7.

Comment: You're also posting images of text...

Answer (score 0):

[`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) was [added in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#typing). You're (indirectly) trying to use it in Python 3.7.

It appears that `typing.Literal` is being used internally in [`elevenslab`](https://pypi.org/project/elevenlabs/), so you won't be able to mitigate this by using [`typing-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) to backport to `Literal` to Python 3.7.

You'll need to upgrade to a more recent version of Python, or downgrade to a version of `elevenslab` that supports Python 3.7. The current latest release of `elevenslab` (v0.2.27) only supports Python 3.8-3.11.

Also note that [Python 3.7 reached it end of life in June of 2023](https://devguide.python.org/versions/), so it would be a good idea to upgrade to a maintained version regardless of how you resolve this issue.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I upgraded and everything works fine.